# Why is ggplot is turning my plot into a list

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, histogram

[image: Dataframe wanting to plot]

The image is 5 rows and two variables I am wanting to plot and below is my code I am using.

The second image shows the results
[image: List of AvgPwill]

```
#histogram plot
Pwill1 <- ggplot(AvgPWill, aes(Segment))+geom_histogram()

#Structure of AvgPWill
str(AvgPWill)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Segment: chr  "Costcutter" "Innovator" "Mercedes" "Workhorse" ...
 $ Values : num  2084 3595 4695 2994 3422
```

I am not familiar with the plot function but I tried this and received this error:

```
plot(AvgPWill$Segment, AvgPWill$Values)
```

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Maybe try `plot(Pwill1)`

Comment: Try `Pwill1 <- ggplot(AvgPWill, aes(Values))+geom_histogram()`

Comment: Still a list using Pwill1 <- ggplot(AvgPWill, aes(Values))+geom_histogram()

Comment: qplot(AvgPWill$Segment, AvgPWill$Values) creates a plot but I cannot seem to get beyond doing this scatterplot

Comment: That worked @Dave2e. I would like to mark that as the answer. Thank you for your help with that answer and editing. I'm still relatively new to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the output from the ggplot function is a list containing the structure of the plot. To display the plot use: `print(Pwill1)`.

Also since you have only 5 rows of data, I believe you want to use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_histogram()`.

```
Values= runif(5, 2000, 3000)
AvgPWill = data.frame(Segment=LETTERS[1:5], Values)

library(ggplot2)
Pwill1 <- ggplot(AvgPWill, aes(x=Segment, y=Values))+geom_col()
print(Pwill1)
```

If you want to use the base graphics then try `barplot()`